# How Do I Get My Navigation Bar To Stretch Across The Screen?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I have the navigation links where I want them, but I want the bar to stretch the full-width of the page. Basically, I want a blue line across the whole length of the screen and the links to stay where they are. I've tried "width:100%" but when I do that, the links become a vertical list again, instead of a horizontal line.

```css
.navbar {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.navbar2 {
 float:right;
 background-color:#1a75ff;
}

.navbar3 {
 display:block;
 padding:14px 16px;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}

li a.active {
 background-color: #0047b3;
 display:block;
 padding:14px 16px;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#contactme">Contact Me</a></li>
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#appointment">Make An Appointment</a></li>
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#aboutme">About Me & My Job</a></li>
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: You haven't included enough code.  Show the markup all the way up to the `html` and `body` tags.  If this navbar is inside a container (which it clearly is, since `body` is a container), then it's conceivable that those container(s) and their style(s) are preventing this from going full width.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to using `display: flex;` below instead of using `float`s like you were doing above, lemme know if this is right:

```css
.navbar {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar2 {
 background-color:#1a75ff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar3 {
 display:block;
 padding:14px 16px;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}

.navbar2.active {
 background-color: #0047b3;
  color:white;
}

li a.active {
 background-color: #0047b3;
 display:block;
 padding:14px 16px;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#contactme">Contact Me</a></li>
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#appointment">Make An Appointment</a></li>
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
  <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#aboutme">About Me & My Job</a></li>
  <li class="navbar2 active"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I sure like the way `flex` looks in this case.  You could remove all those classes from the original question :) - they aren't helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct to put `width:100%` was on the right track, however there were a combination of other styles interfering:

1. The navbar `li` items being floated was unnecessary, and causing other issues.  I created the same effect by applying `text-align: right` to the `.navbar`
2. The navbar `li` items needed to be `display: inline-block` to display as desired.  Otherwise, they were assuming the width of the container because the `a` inside of them are `display: block`
3. I additionally removed all the unnecessary classes, and simply styled the `li` by using the `.navbar li` selector (same concept for the `a` elements).

LASTLY, I applied a background to the `.navbar` to demonstrate it *is* full width.  If you want it to be blue, simply change the background color to match!

```css
.navbar {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #aaa;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1a75ff;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #0047b3;
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
  <li><a href="#contactme">Contact Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#appointment">Make An Appointment</a></li>
  <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
  <li><a href="#aboutme">About Me & My Job</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because all of the li elements are floated, it hides the height of the parent element. Also the parent element doesn't have a background color.

Here's how I would do it.

```css
.navbar {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#1a75ff;
  display:block;
  text-align:right;
}

.navbar2 {
 display:inline-block;
  background-color:#1a75ff;
}

.navbar3 {
 display:block;
 padding:14px 16px;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}

li a.active {
 background-color: #0047b3;
 display:block;
 padding:14px 16px;
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
 <li class="navbar2"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#aboutme">About Me & My Job</a></li>
    <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#appointment">Make An Appointment</a></li>
    <li class="navbar2"><a class="navbar3" href="#contactme">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your navbar to stretch across any screen width using CSS flexbox. This can be done by adding just a few lines of CSS to your existing code:

```
ul.navbar {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
}

li.navbar2 {
  flex-grow:1;
  align-self:center;
  height:100%;
    background-color:#1a75ff;
}

a.navbar3 {
    display:block;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #0047b3;
    display:block;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
```

You may view the resulting navbar here: 
https://codepen.io/aaronadler/pen/vzBOeN